# Centos closest cousin?

Tags: linux, centos

I'm migrating to a new server space. The server OS  is Centos
I want to install a stats software tool, rstudio

Rstudio offers two choices for linux:

RStudio 1.0.153 - Ubuntu 12.04-15.10/Debian 8 (64-bit)  92.7 MB 2017-07-20
RStudio 1.0.153 - Fedora 19+/RedHat 7+/openSUSE 13.1+ (64-bit)

Which should I choose for a Centos install?
(Praying the answer isn't "neither")

Comment: CentOS is a recompile of RedHat/RHEL.  It tries to be identical except for swapping the names, so go with RedHat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Which should I choose for a Centos install?

You should pick the following option:

> - RStudio 1.0.153 - Fedora 19+/RedHat 7+/openSUSE 13.1+ (64-bit)

CentOS is a recompiled version of Redhat Enterprise Linux Server (RHLS) minus the Enterprise only modules, the Redhat Subscription module would be an example of a module not included with CentOS, due to restrictions dealing with the name Redhat (and the fact it serves no purpose if your using CentOS) there are other examples but the list is extensive.

> Red Hat released Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.4 on August 1st, 2017 (Info).  In the CentOS world, we call this type of release a 'Point Release', meaning that the major version of a distribution (in this case Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7) is getting a new point in time update set (in this case '.4').
>
> When there is a new release of RHEL 7 source code, the public release of this source code happens on the CentOS git server (git.centos.org).  We then use a published set of tools (tools) to build Source RPMs (info) from the released git source code and immediately start building the updated version of CentOS Linux.  We use a program called mock to build Binary RPM packages from the SRPMs.

[Source](https://seven.centos.org/2017/08/centos-linux-7-1708-based-on-rhel-7-4-source-code/)